# Alert User When Changing Navigation or When Going to Specific Screen on React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

So I'm currently trying to make a trigger event whenever the user is about to go to a specific page. Say for example I'm on a the Cart page and I decide to go back to the Dashboard page, I want to be able to prompt the user that he's about to leave the Cart page and go back to the Dashboard page. How can I do that in react-native?

Comment: onclick on back button you can do a alert

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code on back button press

```
onPressBack = () = {
  // Works on both iOS and Android
    Alert.alert(
      'Alert Title',
      'You are about to leave this screen',
      [
        {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
        {text: 'OK', onPress: () => this.props.navigation.navigate('DashboardScreen') //code to navigate},
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    )
}
```